# How can I set a deeply nested value in Immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

When working with plain JavaScript objects it's easy to change a deeply nested object property:

```
people.Thomas.nickname = "Mr. T";
```

But with Immutable I have to go through each property's ancestors before I have a new people object:

```
var thomas = peopleImmutable.get("Thomas");
var newThomas = thomas.set("nickname", "Mr .T");
peopleImmutable = peopleImmutable.set("Thomas", newThomas);
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Maps in Immutable have a [setIn method](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn) that makes it easy to set deep values:

```
peopleImmutable = peopleImmutable.setIn(["Thomas", "nickname"], "Mr. T");
```

Or, using `split` to generate the array:

```
peopleImmutable = peopleImmutable.setIn("Thomas.nickname".split("."), "Mr. T");
```

Comment: How would you toggle a boolean using setIn? For example: peopleImmutable = peopleImmutable.setIn(["Thomas", hasNickName], toggleBooleanHere);

Comment: @zero_cool: I suppose peopleImmutable = peopleImmutable.setIn(["Thomas", "hasNickName"], !peopleImmutable.getIn(["Thomas", "hasNickName"]));` (untested)

Comment: @VincentSels This worked perfectly! What about changing all of the booleans in a deeply nested immutable object from false to true in one block? For example: options = fromJS({ one:{selected: false}, two: { selected: false} }). I'm in React, and trying to iterate through the object, and use setIn, but the state only gets set for the last key set.

Comment: Also check out the documentation for `update` and `updateIn` which instead of a `value` parameter takes a function parameter which passes the current value as an argument. So you could do something like `peopleImmutable.updateIn(["Thomas", "isAwesome"], value => !value)`